# Census Tracts Overlay for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to map data by census tract on Google Maps? Specifically, it would be good to know if this capability exists within Qlikview's Google Maps extension, but it would also help to know if this is something that can be done at all, and if so how.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it appears so.

Census tract data is available via a KML file:
https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/kml-cartographic-boundary-files.html

As part of a larger set of Census related data this is available in KML:
https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files.html

The following are directions from Google on how to use KML files with their products:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

Comment: Links are fixed